# can't draw square on canvas

Tags: javascript, html

hey guys I'm starting a snake game in JavaScript. Right now I'll I'm trying to do is paint a little green square in the center of the canvas. I've set the fillStyle and used the fillRect method, but I get nothing. Could somebody explain the issue, I'd really appreciate it, thanks:)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
ctx.fillRect(375, 250, 10, 10);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake Game</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 750px;
   height: 500px;
   
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the dimensions of your canvas are too small (ie the default dimensions of 300w x 150h) meaning that the green rectangle is drawn at [375,250] which is outside of the canvas' dimensions.

Try setting the `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas (ie to match your styles) as follows:

```
canvas.width = 750;
canvas.height = 500;
```

This will ensure that the canvas resolution/dimensions are appropriatly set causing the rectangle to be visible.

**The key take away:** the canvas has it's own concept of dimensions. These are not inherited from any CSS styling that is applied to the canvas.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Necessary to specify the resolution of the canvas
// explicitly by doing this:
canvas.width = 750;
canvas.height = 500;

ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
ctx.fillRect(375, 250, 10, 10);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Snake Game</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    canvas {
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 750px;
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation and not just the answer,  much love:)